# Cropping a rectangle on a rotated image

Tags: c++, image, graphics, ogre

I have the following situation. The picture on the right is what I have as a texture.. I can access it's pixels. The origin of it is at top left. The image on the left is the expected image, but unfortunately its not possible to rotate the image and fix it.

The situation is : I'm getting screen coordinates from world coordinates and I assume its correct. Screen coordiantes as usual its top left 0,0 x positive, y positive down 
Now I want to crop the image based on screen coordinates.. The Ogre box raises an exception meaning that the box is not correct.

How would I fix the math and the code in that situation ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFQZL.png)

```
        int min_x = 0;
        int min_y = 0;
        int max_x = 0;
        int max_y = 0;
        float screenPositionX =512 - screenPosition.x;
        float screenPositionY =1024 - screenPosition.y;

        min_x = std::max( 0, (int) screenPositionX );
        min_y = std::max( 0, (int) screenPositionY );
        max_x = std::min( (int)512, (int) screenPositionX + radius );
        max_y = std::min( (int)1024, (int) screenPositionY + radius );
        // Get the pixelbox within the radius.
        Ogre::Box regionBox( (int)screenPositionX, (int)screenPositionY, 512, 1024  );
```

Comment: First, 8 lines of your code are not used. Second, which values do you got for the box?

Comment: @TobiasWollgam The strange thing I tried a value of a box (0,0,512,1024) and I get a cropped image, but for (0,0,128,128) I get scanned lines image, I don't know how it works

Comment: Ok, but this is a thing you don't ask and there is no code. To solve the exception problem the calculated values for the box are needed.

Comment: @TobiasWollgam How would I calculate the correct values for Ogre::Box ? that's my question